# Declaring variables in in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran95

Why does this piece of code not work and what is the alternative?

```
module find_integers_module  
  implicit none
  contains  
  integer function function1(r) result(rnext)   
    implicit none   
    integer,intent(in) :: r     
    integer :: k = r    
    rnext = -1          
  end function function1     
end module
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fortran standard requires that the *rhs* of the initialisation in `integer :: k = r` be a *constant-expression*; you might care to think of that as *computable at compile-time* though that's not how the standard puts it.

The workaround is simple:

```
integer :: k
k = r
```